# Is there a way to get inputs using their keys in Python's PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I would like to know how to get a value (Text Input Box) using it's key but I don't really know how.

I think you can use `values['key_name_here']` but I am not sure. I have tried that but it didn't seem to work. (At least I tried it on a text label)

I also need to get the text from a label but so far I can't see how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go back to the basic introduction to PySimpleGUI ([Jumpstart](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#jump-start)), this tells you how to get the Text Input Box value.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
            [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

You can see from the initialisation the line `window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)` passes a list (layout) to the variable "window".

In the event loop, the state of Text Input Box is handled by `event, values = window.read()`, passing the text to "values". Values is a list, not a dictionary, which is why you don't access it by `values['Inp1']`; you access it by the list index `values[0]` (presumably if there was more than one InputBox, the next one would be `values[1]`).

Alternately, once the event loop is started, you can get the InputBox value directly using `.get()`: `print(f'Label 1 is {layout[1][1].get()}')`

Getting the text of a label is a bit obscure. The answer is to use `.DisplayText`: `print(f'Label 1 is {layout[0][0].DisplayText}')`

An example using direct access:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
            [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])
    # This is a directly accessed Label
    print(f'Label 1 is {layout[0][0].DisplayText}')
    # This is directly accessed InputBox
    print(f'Label 1 is {layout[1][1].get()}')
    # Note that layout is a list of lists

window.close()
```

There are different ways in Python to build dynamic strings. One of the latest, and my personal choice usually, is f-strings ([Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)). These are marked by putting an 'f' in front of the string `f'Label 1 is {layout[1][1].get()}'`.

The order of widgets is defined by the layout. Each row is a list of widgets, and then all the lists are added to the layout container. This means the first row of widgets is layout[0]. The first widget on the first row is layout[0][0].

Comment: I don't understand what the `f` does `print(f'Text')`

Comment: Also, how do I know what number is what when using layout?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the details about f-strings and layout index.